# Is 3.3nf the same as 330nf?

Tags: capacitor

This is a real simple newbie question but is 3.3nf the same as 330nf?

I am struggling to work out the conversion and want to make sure I am not putting the wrong thing into my circuit!

Comment: Maybe I am reading your question wrong but...is $3.30 the same as $330?

Comment: No it is not, is this the answer to my question or a riddle? :)

Comment: Well, I'm just saying... 3.3 nanofarads is obviously not the same as 330 nanofarads. Did you maybe mean microfarads? millifarads?

Comment: Toss in component markings such as 332 (3.3nF) and 334 (330nF) where the last digit is a power of ten in picofarads and perhaps it becomes easier to see how someone new to the field could be confused by the whole subject area.

Comment: "Unclear what you are asking?" Come on people, lets quit it with the blatantly false close vote reasons.  There is nothing the slightest bit unclear about the question

Comment: It *is* a little unclear...what conversion is needed here? That's why I said maybe OP meant a different prefix. (Perhaps a typo, with 'm' being next to 'n' on the keyboard and all.)

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I think the general assumption is that the OP can't possibly be asking "Is 3.3 = 330", because that would be more stupid then I believe someone who can string two words together could possibly be. As such, the OP is *probably* using the incorrect term for something.

Comment: The OP is indeed asking that, as they promptly accepted an answer which answers it.  Just because something is obvious to you does not make it obvious to everyone new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, 3.3nf is not 330nf. (Thirty Characters)

Comment: forty three characters